# Ejecutar script bash para multiples carpetas

Tags: bash, script, shell

trabajo con archivos de tipo CSV, para ello tengo un script de bash que para una carpeta genera una carpeta con N copias del archivo que contenga.
Por ejemplo, si una carpeta tiene 10 archivos dentro, genera 10 carpetas con el nombre de cada archivo original y dentro N copias del archivo original.

Incluyo mi codigo:

```
cd pruebas
for x in ./*.csv; do
    mkdir "${x%.*}" 
    for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do # Create a loop, looping 50 times
    cp "$x" "${x%.*}/copy_$x_$i.csv" # use i in the copy command
    #rm -f "$x" # Remove the file after the 50 copies
    done
done
```

El problema que tengo es para automatizar este script y que recorra todas las carpetas y genere todos los archivos/copias, he buscado pero no he tenido exito, agradezco de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme a resolver esta parte, saludos.

Comment: sería poner un bucle fuera del `for` actual, ¿no? `for directorio en **; do ... for x in directorio/*.csv`

Comment: deacuerdo, voy a probar con esa idea, muchas gracias